# JWT token validation Problem with GO and Go-Gin

Tags: go, jwt, go-gin

I'm following an Youtube tutorial to work with (GIN + GO + JWT). I've implemented the Token validation middleware. It workes fine JWT configured cookie is passed with request. Without token It blocks the request with 401 error but also causes 500 server error. Had gone through the JWT [doc](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/golang-jwt/jwt/v4#example-Parse-Hmac) but couldn't solve the issue.

## Middleware:

---

```golang
package middleware

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/fahad-md-kamal/go-jwt/initializers"
    "github.com/fahad-md-kamal/go-jwt/models"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/golang-jwt/jwt/v4"
)

func RequrieAuth(c *gin.Context) {
    // Get the cookie off req
    tokenString, err := c.Cookie("Authorization")
    
    if err != nil  {
        c.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusUnauthorized)
    }

    // Decode/validate it
    token, err := jwt.Parse(tokenString, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        if _, ok := token.Method.(*jwt.SigningMethodHMAC); !ok {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("Unexpected signing method: %v", token.Header["alg"])
        }
    
        return []byte(os.Getenv("SECRET")), nil
    })

    if token == nil {
        // fmt.Println(token.Valid)
        c.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusUnauthorized)
    }

    if claims, ok := token.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims); ok{

        if float64(time.Now().Unix()) > claims["exp"].(float64){
            c.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusUnauthorized)
        }
        // Find the user with token sub
        var user models.User
        initializers.DB.First(&user,claims["sub"])
        
        if user.ID == 0 {
            c.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusUnauthorized)
        }

        // Attach to req
        c.Set("user", user)

        // Continue
        c.Next()

        } else {
        c.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusUnauthorized)
    }
}
```

## ERROR:

---

```bash
2022/09/30 18:50:47 [Recovery] 2022/09/30 - 18:50:47 panic recovered:
GET /validate HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 102
Content-Type: application/json
Postman-Token: 9950b831-aa25-4ba3-a1eb-17c0fd8db5b4
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.2


runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
/usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:260 (0x104c475)
        panicmem: panic(memoryError)
/usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:835 (0x104c445)
        sigpanic: panicmem()
/Users/genex/Desktop/golang/jwt/middleware/requireAuth.go:37 (0x168016a)
        RequrieAuth: if claims, ok := token.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims); ok{
/Users/genex/golang/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.8.1/context.go:173 (0x166e361)
        (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
/Users/genex/golang/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.8.1/recovery.go:101 (0x166e34c)
        CustomRecoveryWithWriter.func1: c.Next()
/Users/genex/golang/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.8.1/context.go:173 (0x166d466)
        (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
/Users/genex/golang/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.8.1/logger.go:240 (0x166d449)
        LoggerWithConfig.func1: c.Next()
/Users/genex/golang/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.8.1/context.go:173 (0x166c530)
        (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
/Users/genex/golang/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.8.1/gin.go:616 (0x166c198)
        (*Engine).handleHTTPRequest: c.Next()
/Users/genex/golang/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.8.1/gin.go:572 (0x166bcdc)
        (*Engine).ServeHTTP: engine.handleHTTPRequest(c)
/usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:2947 (0x12a7dab)
        serverHandler.ServeHTTP: handler.ServeHTTP(rw, req)
/usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1991 (0x12a2fc6)
        (*conn).serve: serverHandler{c.server}.ServeHTTP(w, w.req)
/usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1594 (0x1067740)
        goexit: BYTE    $0x90   // NOP

[GIN-debug] [WARNING] Headers were already written. Wanted to override status code 401 with 500
[GIN] 2022/09/30 - 18:50:47 | 500 |    6.815587ms |             ::1 | GET      "/validate"
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is an `invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference` in line 37

```
if _, ok := token.Method.(*jwt.SigningMethodHMAC); !ok {
```

That's because `token` is `nil` here. (You write that this happens *Without token*.)

It says in the [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.Abort):

*AbortWithStatus calls Abort()…*
*Abort prevents pending handlers from being called. Note that this will **not stop** the current handler.* (empasis by me)

So you need `return` statements after your calls to `c.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusUnauthorized)` to exit your function in case of an error.